# Using 'optional' properties in a MATLAB class

Tags: matlab, oop, optional-parameters

I've a question concerning classes in MATLAB.

I'm writing a parser, that doesn't always have the same input. Some variables are not defined at all times. Here is a short mock up script:

**test_parser.m**

```
classdef test_parser < matlab.mixin.Copyable
    properties (AbortSet = true)
        a
        b        
    end
end
```

**make_class.m**

```
function result = make_class(array)
    result = test_parser;
    result.a = array(1);
    if length(array)>1
        result.b=array(2);
    end
end
```

Now calling from the command window with different input lengths:

```
>> make_class([10])
ans =     
  test_parser with properties:    
    a: 10
    b: []

>> make_class([10,20])        
ans =     
  test_parser with properties:    
    a: 10
    b: 20
```

In both cases the variable `b` is a property of `test_parser`, as specified. My wish would be, that `b` is optional, so just present if there is `b` in the input.

What is the best way to achieve this? I guess an optional parameter is not really a property?

Comment: If this is purely for aesthetic reasons then I'd say the solution would be to keep the code clean (that's the important bit!) and instead of relying on "lack of semi-colon" to display the output, simply create a small function to display the class's values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want optional properties, you can inherit your class from [`dynamicprops`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dynamicprops-class.html). You can then add properties on the fly using the command `addprop`, test whether a property exists using `isprop`, and even respond to properties being added or removed by listening to the events `PropertyAdded` and `PropertyRemoved`.

In your example, you would then use:

```
classdef test_parser < matlab.mixin.Copyable & dynamicprops
    properties (AbortSet = true)
        a       
    end
end

function result = make_class(array)
    result = test_parser;
    result.a = array(1);
    if length(array)>1
        result.addprop('b')
        result.b=array(2);
    end
end

>> make_class([10])
ans = 
  test_parser with properties:

    a: 10
>> make_class([10,20])
ans = 
  test_parser with properties:

    a: 10
    b: 20
```

Comment: This one, is a great idea! I will try that on monday. ;-)